# Naming a coordination compound

Tags: nomenclature, coordination-compounds, ions, oxidation-state

I was asked to determine the coordination compound which has the name:

$$\text{triamminetrinitritocobalt(I)}$$

I thought it must be: $$\ce{[Co(NH3)3(ONO)3]^2-}$$

The $-2$ charge can be deduced by adding up the oxidation numbers.

However, in this case, shouldn't the name be written as *cobaltate* instead of *cobalt*? Where is my mistake and what did I miss here?

Comment: -ate is used for if metal has a latin name

Comment: In coordination compunds nomenclature, -ate is used when the complex has a net negative charge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct: an *-ate* prefix is used when the complex has a net negative charge and the name should be *triamminetrinitritocobaltate(I) ion*

**Reference:**

> If the overall coordination complex is an anion, the ending "-ate" is attached to the metal center. Some metals also change to their Latin names in this situation. The rest of the metals simply have -ate added to the end (cobaltate, nickelate, zincate, osmate, cadmate, platinate, mercurate, etc. Note that the -ate tends to replace -um or -ium, if present).

[Chemistry Libretexts - Nomenclature of Coordination compounds](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Inorganic_Chemistry)/Coordination_Chemistry/Structure_and_Nomenclature_of_Coordination_Compounds/Nomenclature_of_Coordination_Complexes)